# Getting OOZIE error E0900: Jobtracker [localhost:8021] not allowed, not in Oozies whitelist]

Tags: hadoop, oozie

I am trying to run the Oozie examples on the CDH virtual machine.  I have Cloudera Manager running and I execute the following command:

```
oozie job -oozie http://localhost:11000/oozie -config examples/apps/map-reduce/job.properties -run
```

when I check the status I get the HadoopAccessorException.

I checked the oozie log and I see the following stack trace:

```
2013-07-22 14:25:56,179 WARN org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionStartXCommand:
USER[cloudera] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[map-reduce-wf] JOB[0000001-130722142323751-oozie
oozi-W] ACTION[0000001-130722142323751-oozie-oozi-W@mr-node] Error starting action
[mr-node]. ErrorType [ERROR], ErrorCode [HadoopAccessorException], Message
[HadoopAccessorException: E0900: Jobtracker  not allowed, not in
Oozies whitelist] org.apache.oozie.action.ActionExecutorException:
HadoopAccessorException: E0900: Jobtracker not allowed, not in Oozies
Whitelist
```

The oozie-site.xml and the oozie-default.xml have the `oozie.service.HadoopAccessorService.jobTracker.whitelist` and `oozie.service.HadoopAccessorService.nameNode.whitelist` set.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Dave

Answer (score 1):

I believe Cloudera Manager doesn't read your **oozie-site.xml** file and rather maintains its own config somewhere.

You should be able to go in the UI into **Oozie Server Role**, **Processes**, **Configuration Files/Environment** and click on **Show** and this is where you can define the whitelists for your Oozie server, as opposed to just doing it in the files.

Once this is changed, restart Oozie and you should be able to execute your command.

[source](http://grokbase.com/t/cloudera/scm-users/12bgn6w3fa/job-submission-in-oozie)

Comment: I have a similar error but with NameNode. The configuration page in Cloudera Manager does not include the **oozie.service.HadoopAccessorService.jobTracker.whitelist** or the **oozie.service.HadoopAccessorService.nameNode.whitelist** properties. In addition, I didn't have to set these on the cluster I installed manually.

Comment: Hi, could you explain a little bit where to put the settings? I am getting this error message

Comment: [cloudera@localhost oozie-3.3.2+92]$ oozie job -oozie http://localhost:11000/oozie -config examples/apps/hive/job.properties -run
Error: E0901 : E0901: Namenode [localhost:8020] not allowed, not in Oozies whitelis

Answer (score 1):

I know i am very late on this but someone looking for answers might find this helpful. I got similar error i went into the the location on Cloudera manager  *UI into Oozie Server Role, Processes, Configuration Files/Environment*

And clicked on oozie-site.xml link and looked at the below property

```
<property>
<name>oozie.service.HadoopAccessorService.nameNode.whitelist</name>
<value>server1:8020,server2:8020,**<name>**</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>oozie.service.HadoopAccessorService.jobTracker.whitelist</name>
<value>server1:8032,server2:8032,**yarnRM**</value>
</property>
```

I used yarnRM as my value on the jobtracker in the workflow.xml file and it went past the error while running the workflow.